# Name 'y' is not defined, python code to find even or odd numbers

Tags: python

I am writing a simple code to find even or odd numbers, the code was working just fine but maybe I did something wrong and it started giving me this error.

> File "d:\Python\EvenOddFinder.py", line 12, in restart
>       restartornot = input()
>     File "", line 1, in 
>   NameError: name 'y' is not defined

```
    #Even or Odd Number Finder.
def start():
    userInput = input("Please input your number:")
    userInput = int(userInput)
    if userInput %2 == 0:
        print("The number " + str(userInput) + " is Even.")
    else:
        print("The number " + str(userInput) + " is Odd.")
    def restart():
        print("Do you want to restart?")
        print("Y/N")
        restartornot = input()
        if restartornot == "Y":
            start()
        elif restartornot == "y":
            start()
        elif restartornot == "N":
            exit()
        elif restartornot == "n":
            exit()
        else:
            print("Invalid Input.")
            restart()
    restart()
start()
```

Please help me I am quite new to Python.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Your code works fine. Could you elaborate more on your problem?

Comment: It works fine till it gives me the answer but when it asks me to restart or not and if I enter "Y" it gives me the error.

Comment: Using python 3, it works fine for me too. If i answer "Y" it asks again as expected. Using python2, it gives the error you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Python 2 you should try using

```
restartornot = raw_input()
```

Comment: Actually I am using Python 3. According to it the code should work fine.

Comment: @Sumedh Are you *sure* you're using python 3? Because the error you described can't happen with the given code in python 3. I think maybe you have both python 2 and python 3 installed, and you're accidentally invoking it with python 2.

Comment: @Dr.Greg `if restartornot == "Y" or "y":` is [not correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-against-a-value).